# Applying machine learning to dynamic complex systems (e.g. weather prediction)

Tags: overfitting, philosophical, application

Would it be correct to say that:

1. Physics-based, domain specific models are more widely used and are more practical in (longer term) weather forecasts than pure machine learning approaches
2. The reason for the above is that the world, i.e. the population we are dealing with, is always changing; a model that works very well on a particular dataset (and does not overfit in the machine learning sense) can work very poorly in practice as the world is constantly changing in ways that are nearly impossible to capture in any single dataset. In other words, the future may be sampled from a very different population than what our dataset was sampled from; but we may not have a way of knowing that our machine learning model is now making poor predictions, especially if such predictions are long-term. Physics-based models can predict such changes and are therefore better in generalizing to evolving conditions and changing data population.
3. Therefore pure machine learning models in (long term) weather forecasting can be said to be overfitting to past history of a dynamic complex system.

Is my understanding of the limitations of applying machine learning to dynamic complex systems reasonable?

Comment: Try googling for "deep learning for weather forcasting" lots of interesting hits